# Assigning new auto increment value

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql, auto-increment, identity

I have a table that is created as below.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table1](
    [ID] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Title] [VARCHAR](255) NULL,
    ...
```

Lets say that the latest ID is 100 ( I have 100 records)

Is there a way to `ALTER` this table's `IDENTITY` column and change the auto increment value to now be 500?

So at the end i would have something like this 
ID 98, 99, 100, 500, 501, ....

I can not seem to find a solution for this in T-SQL

Comment: What version of SQL are you using and why do you want to do this?

Comment: SQLServer 2008 R2, because I am starting to use a new front end system and I would like the IDs to begin with a pre determined ID (500) so that i can easily tell if data was entered in old system (ID<500) or new system (ID>500)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [`DBCC CHECKIDENT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176057(v=sql.105).aspx) to reseed the `IDENTITY` column.

Here is a sample you can run:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
USE tempdb;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.foo(ID INT IDENTITY(1,1));
GO

INSERT dbo.foo DEFAULT VALUES;
GO 100

-- note: set it to ([the next value you want] - 1)
DBCC CHECKIDENT(N'dbo.foo', RESEED, 499);
GO

INSERT dbo.foo DEFAULT VALUES;
GO 3

SELECT ID FROM dbo.foo WHERE ID >= 98;
```

Results:

```
98
99
100
500
501
502
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following [MSDN_DBCC CHECKIDENT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176057.aspx) Hope that helps!

**DBCC CHECKIDENT (Transact-SQL)**

> You can use DBCC CHECKIDENT to manually set a new current identity
>   value for the identity column.

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT 
 ( 
    table_name
        [, { NORESEED | { RESEED [, new_reseed_value ] } } ]
)
[ WITH NO_INFOMSGS ]
```

---

Example

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;
GO
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('Person.AddressType', RESEED, 10);
GO
```